# Listview "like" button inside cell

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I´m trying to set a "like button" inside the cells of my listview. To do that I´m using this code:

```
public class MyCell : ViewCell
{
    private SvgCachedImage likeImg = new SvgCachedImage();

    public MyCell()
    {
        likeImg.Source = SvgImageSource.FromFile("notlike.svg");
        likeImg.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = new Command(() => LikeFnc()) });

        View = likeImg;
    }

    private void LikeFnc()
    {
        likeImg.Source = SvgImageSource.FromFile("like.svg");
    }
}
```

This works, but the behavior is very strange since the images of several cells are changed, it is as if the function to change the image affected other cells. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Cells are reused on repeaters like listview to avoid overprocessing and hangs. It's like the same instance shared between items on your list. I guess you can make it work by using a boolean property and 2 instances of `SvgCachedImage `, one for each desired image. Chose the SvgCachedImage to show depending on the state of BoolProperty. You can use bindings on it too.

Comment: Ok, I made it using MessagingCenter. Thanks